# Aggregation of the patterns for large amount of URL requests

Tags: logging, statistics

I see there is a need to get statistic data from large amount of URL request, for example, from HTTPD request logs. The idea is to know the percentage of different kind of requests, IE. aggregate them into different buckets.

I know one approach is to define the pattern of different request manually. However, is there some existing tool/algorithm, that have a smart and adaptive algorithm to aggregate based on the common prefixes seen in the URLs?

For example, if the URLs in the logs are like this:

```
/api/docker/a/..
/api/docker/a/..
/api/docker/a/..
... (repeat a lot, all started with /api/docker/a)
/api/docker/b/..
/api/docker/b/..
... (repeat a lot, all started with /api/docker/b)
/api/token
/api/token
```

Then I would expect the smart tool/algorithm to output like:

```
/api/docker/a    M
/api/docker/b    N
/api/token       2
```

The tool/algorithm shall be able to aggregate in a smart way based on statistic of the data itself, that no or few human input needs to be provided.